# single sql database entry with muliple values into an array

Tags: php, arrays

the script querys database and retrieves a single entry that has mulitple numbers

`SELECT jnum from database where x = y`

> output = 11111,22222,33333,44444

So i explode that on `,` and get `$variable[0] = 11111` and `$variable[1]= 22222`

What i want to do is perform a query on another table using each of those numbers (numbers will be different each time and there may be any number of numbers).

is there a way to structure a foreach for each entry in the array or a while loop that counts so that i can query the database for each of the values i get from output above.

i don't know if i am conveying what 'im trying to do here very clearly so i apologize in advance.

i get a single entry for the database table and it contains a string (11111,22222,33333)
i explode on , and get the array variable[] 
there will not always be 3 entries sometime there could be 5 or 7 or 10 or 1 but each one will be unique.
but for each value i want to query a db table and retrieve all the rows that have that single number(`$variable[]`) as an entry.
Not sure if a loop count or a foreach statement would work. any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you parsing data in your table that relates to other columns?  This sort of defeats the purpose of using a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming these are values in a single column there is no need to look you can use `WHERE ... IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM the_other_table WHERE some_col IN ('11111','22222','33333')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out foreach loops - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach ($variable as $value) {

    $myquery = "some query using $value";
    // then execute your query
 }
```

Comment: ok i understand this part but my problem is the $variable is actually an array with values, there could be one number or ten. for example in your foreach the $variable is actually $variable[$x] with $x being one of the numbers from the string, but i need to change $x from 1 to 2 to 3 for each entry that is in the area.